# Error when try to send email with sendEmail

Tags: email, tcp, smtp, port, sendmail

I want to use sendEmail to send automated emails.
If i run the following line separately it works:

```
sendemail.exe -f "payslip@dgroup.com" -t "dn.john@dgroup.com" -u "Payslip: DN JOHN, marca 1567, may 2021" -o message-file=mail_body_payslip.txt -o tls=no -o username="payslip@dgroup.com" -o password="hfsjfb&^%"  -s webmail.dgroup.com:26 -o timeout=5 -xu payslip@dgroup.com -xp hfsjfb&^% -a "C:\Payslips\encrypted\2021_05_1702_DN_JOHN.pdf" -l email_log.txt
```

However if i try to run it from a bat file it doesn't work.
Here is the bat file:

```
@echo.
@echo.
echo Starting email session... >> email_log.txt
date /t >> email_log.txt
time /t >> email_log.txt
@echo.
@echo Verifying files...


@echo.
@echo Sending mails...
sendemail.exe -f "payslip@dgroup.com" -t "dn.john@dgroup.com" -u "Payslip: DN JOHN, marca 1567, may 2021" -o message-file=mail_body_payslip.txt -o tls=no -o username="payslip@dgroup.com" -o password="hfsjfb&^%"  -s webmail.dgroup.com:26 -o timeout=5 -xu payslip@dgroup.com -xp hfsjfb&^% -a "C:\Payslips\encrypted\2021_05_1702_DN_JOHN.pdf" -l email_log.txt

@echo.
@echo.
@echo Payslip was sent. Verify email_log.txt
@echo.
@pause
```

When i run the bat file I get the following error:

```
Jun 16 14:01:55 srv3 sendemail.exe[2532]: ERROR => Connection attempt to localhost:25 failed: IO::Socket::INET: connect: Unknown error
```

If I run telnet localhost:25 I get this:

```
Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed
```

What could be the problem? Why is running fine separately but executed from bat file I get error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.
When you run the bat file the "%" character found in the password was replaced with "26" therefore the password was incorrect.
The solution is to use %% instead of %.
Two %% equals to one %.